# Using -L and -l flags vs giving library file as input

Tags: c++, linker

What's the difference between writing:

`g++ test.cc -L/my/dir/ -lname`

and

`g++ test.cc /my/dir/libname.so` ?

Are both correct?

The things that I can think of:

1. First one is cross platform, g++ from MINGW will look for DLL's
2. In the second one we explicitly specify we want dynamic linking

Comment: First method is more universal - it will look multiple directories and would support either dynamic or static lib. Also first one will work on different OS, second one only where shared lib have `.so` extention

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that

> ```
> g++ test.cc -L/my/dir/ -lname
> ```

may succeed even if `/my/dir/libname.so` does not exist:

- It can find `libname.so` from a system library directory (usually `/lib`, `/usr/lib`).
- It can find `libname.a`, and do static linking.

Furthermore, it allows you to link to multiple libraries from the same directory without repeating the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

The first method looks into /my/dir directory for the library file at link time. However  only a short library name `libname.so` (or whatever it finds according to OS) is written into the image. When the program starts, it will look for the library in some library path, i.e. LD_LIBRARY_PATH on linux. Now you can relocate the executable and the library into different new places and set a correct search path after relocation.

The second method writes the full path of the library into the image: `/my/dir/libname.so`. When the program starts, it will look for this particular path to get the library. This makes the image non-relocatable, unless the same library path exists in the new environment. The effect is similar to the '-rpath' method.